# Volley POST operation

Tags: java, android, android-volley

```
String url = "https://www.maishainfotech.com/adinterview/interview.php";
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
          Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
          res.setText(response.toString());
     }
}, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
          res.setText(error.toString());
     }
}) {
     @Override
     public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
         params.put("email_id", "interview@maishainfotech.com");
         if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
             return encodeParameters(params, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         }
         return null;


     }

};
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

I am supposed to get

```
 {"Response":[{"fname":"Maisha","lname":"ID","type":"customer","number":"7788778878","address":"NSP,Pitampura,Delhi"}]}
```

as response but i am getting

```
 {"Response":[]}
```

can you guys help me out

I tried using `postman` while passing "email_id" as key and "interview@maishainfotech.com" as the value in the body section of `x-www-form-urlencoded` then I am getting the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test it

```
      String url = "https://www.maishainfotech.com/adinterview/interview.php";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
//                res.setText(response.toString());
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.e("asdasd", "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage() );
//                res.setText(error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email_id", "interview@maishainfotech.com");
                return  params;
            }

            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }

        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```